# What is the solution for Configuration failed because libmysqlclient was not found.?

Tags: mysql, r

```
Configuration failed because libmysqlclient was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu 16.04)
        libmariadbclient-dev (Ubuntu 14.04)
 * rpm: mariadb-devel | mysql-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: mysql56_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: mariadb-connector-c (OSX)
If libmysqlclient is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libmysqlclient.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
```

Comment: It looks to me like the error message provides a couple of suggestions: 1 install packages if they are missing, 2 If packages are already installed, check the paths. You can check paths using `Sys.getenv("PATH")`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

intalling mysql client will solve the problem in ubuntu.